# Exchange Export- Multiple Properties (EMC)

Tags: exchange-2010, export

I'm trying a New-MailBoxExportRequest to Export Mailbox to a .pst

If I use this command, everything works!

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox <user> -ContentFilter {Received -lt '05/27/2015 18:00'}-FilePath \\Server\name.pst -ExcludeFolders “#Calendar#” -ExcludeDumpster
```

HOWEVER If I add multiple properties for the diffirent parameters, the command errors out!Invalid Syntax

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox <user> -ContentFilter {Received -lt '05/27/2015 18:00'}{Sent -lt '05/27/2015 18:00'}-FilePath \\Server\name.pst  -ExcludeFolders “#Calendar#,#Contacts#” -ExcludeDumpster
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

You need an operator between your chained filters, like so:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox <user> -ContentFilter {(Received -lt '05/27/2015 18:00') -or (Sent -lt '05/27/2015 18:00')} -FilePath \\Server\name.pst  -ExcludeFolders “#Calendar#,#Contacts#” -ExcludeDumpster
```